# List Comprehension: why is this a syntax error?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-2.6

Why is `print(x)` here not valid (`SyntaxError`) in the following list-comprehension?

```
my_list=[1,2,3]
[print(my_item) for my_item in my_list]
```

To contrast - the following doesn't give a syntax error:

```
def my_func(x):
    print(x)
[my_func(my_item) for my_item in my_list]
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Because print is not a function, it's a statement, and you can't have them in expressions. This gets more obvious if you use normal Python 2 syntax:

```
my_list=[1,2,3]
[print my_item for my_item in my_list]
```

That doesn't look quite right. :) The parenthesizes around my_item tricks you.

This has changed in Python 3, btw, where print *is* a function, where your code works just fine.

Comment: You can import this feature from the future: `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: @THC4k - I agree, this will make sure the code can be compiled in *both* 2.6 and 3.0

Comment: Right, since it specifically mentions 2.6, that's a good point.

Comment: FWIW, in 2.7 and using the future import the above code doesn't work for me. a) I need to use brace syntax, `print(x)` to avoid syntax error msg, b) it emits a trailing list of Nones after printing the list items: https://gist.github.com/maphew/67c88807bf97bf67fbf9

Comment: @mattwilkie: Looking at your gist, that's the expected output. a) since `print` is now a function you need to use the brace syntax, b) you're returning a lists of `None`s since `print` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @LucasGodoy the curious bit is the 2nd part, where brace is being used but print is printing out the list items as expected AND a series of Nones.

Comment: ...and means the final "the above code works just fine" statement is wrong. It doesn't work -- cleanly that is. There's no syntax error but the results are likely unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 9):

list comprehension are designed to create a list. So using print inside it will give an error no-matter we use print() or print in 2.7 or 3.x. The code

```
[my_item for my_item in my_list]
```

makes a new object of type list.

```
print [my_item for my_item in my_list]
```

prints out this new list as a whole

refer : [here](http://repl.it/2X7/8)

Comment: *"no-matter we use print() or print in 2.7 or 3.x"* This is only true for python 2.x, not python 3.x. `[print(char) for char in "abc"]` is valid (but discouraged) in python 3.x

Answer (score 7):

It's a syntax error because `print` is not a function. It's a statement. Since you obviously don't care about the return value from `print` (since it has none), just write the normal loop:

```
for my_item in my_list:
    print my_item
```

Answer (score 0):

print in python 3 makes it more obvious on how to use it.

the square brackets in the list comprehension denotes that the output will actually be a list.
    
    `L1=['a','ab','abc']
    print([item for item in L1])`

   This should do the trick.