# How to print list elements in newlines using brackets?

Tags: python

Assume there is a list `demo_list`:

```
[u'demo', u'trial']
```

Using for loop to print every element with '\n':

```
for i in demo_list:
    print(i)
```

it works as expected:

```
demo
trial
```

However, I would like to use the bracket to express this loop:

```
print([ i for i in demo_list])
```

But it directly prints the whole list in one line:

```
[u'demo', u'trial']
```

For the expression `[print(i) for i in demo_list]`, it says `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

My question is:

1. How to put every element in new lines using the bracket?
2. What is wrong with the expression `[print(i) for i in demo_list]`?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how about `print('\n'.join(demo_list))`? Btw, the `[print(i) for i in demo_list]` does work for me but it is definitely discouraged.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Thanks for your reply, but it returns `[u'demo\ntrial']`. Btw, why is the `[print(i) for i in demo_list]` discouraged? What is the disadvantage of this form?

Comment: _Bracket expressions_ are called list comprehensions, and it is really discouraged to use comprehensions for this purpose. You should try `join` method instead.

Comment: Weird.. What does `type(demo_list)` return?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis `type(demo_list)` returns `<type 'list'>`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis You can use print in list comprehension in Python 3+, but for Python 2.7 it's a statement. You can't.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Thanks for your reply. Why is `[print(i) for i in demo_list]` discouraged?

Comment: @user2894829 Because list-comprehensions are not general-purpose loop tools. They exist to create lists. In your case, you are using their built-in, list-creating loop mechanism to `print`. That's like using a fork to eat soup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as per the error message, you are not using python 3, but 2.7x.
Because your code works in python 3.

In python 2.7, print is not a function, but a statement whose format is print  [,]*. (square brackets indicates optional arguments).

Also list comprehension is a way to create a list. You may see [None, None] at the end, so better you assign it to a variable.

modify your list comprehension to:

```
def print_stmt(x):
    print x

a = [print_stmt(x) for x in ["demo", "trial"]]
```

This will print as:

`demo`

`trial`

Answer (score 1):

How about using a "\n" - newline character with `join` after you generate the list using list comprehension (i.e. the *bracket* expression)?

```
In [29]: demo_list = [u'demo', u'trial']   

In [30]: print("\n".join([ i for i in demo_list])) 
demo
trial
```

---

In general, there no need for list comprehension if you already have the list. A simple join operation with newline char would work fine.

```
In [31]: print("\n".join(demo_list)) 
demo
trial
```

Comment: Why do you need a comprehension for this?

Comment: It's not needed but OP needs this because it says `However, I would like to use the bracket to express this loop:`

Answer (score 1):

It's called **list comprehension**. You cannot use a **statement** in a list comprehension. It's obvious if you see in this way:

```
[assert x for x in lst]

# same as
[print x for x in lst]
```

The `print` in Python 2.7 but not a **function**. So it is a `SyntaxError`. But this works:

```
l = [1,2,3]

def p(x):
    print(x)

map(p, l)
# or
[p(x) for x in l]
```

Reference: [List Comprehension: why is this a syntax error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141098/list-comprehension-why-is-this-a-syntax-error)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
In [591]: from __future__ import print_function
In [592]: print(*demo_list,sep='\n')
demo
trial
```

Answer (score 1):

you can :

```
print(*[i for i in demo_list],sep='\n')
```

or

```
print(*demo_list, sep='\n')
```

if you are using `Python2.7` you should `from __future__ import print_function`.